# cannot find the flags to link with Boost thread

Tags: boost, linker, makefile, configure, autoconf

I'm trying to compile a library requiring boost. I was able to make it work on ubuntu but I don't understand why the ./configure can't find boost_thread on Mac OS X. Boost .hpp are located in /usr/local/include/boost and .dylib and .a are located in /usr/local/lib

Here's the log file of configure : http://pastebin.com/KKqareyT

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Did you check that your boost libs are named this way (`libboost_thread-xgcc42-mt-1_50.a` etc.)?

Comment: I found the solution, there is some problem with boost => 1.50 Going back to boost 1.49 fixed it.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with Boost1.50, I guess they just changed the default naming. Set `--layout=versioned` option in `bjam` line.